# iReport Group Expression Multiple Fields

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

How could i write a Group Expression in `iReport` with Multiple Fields ? Report output should be as below.

```
Buyer   Product Unit    Quantity    Total
------------------------------------------
Buyer2  Banana  Count    50
                                    50
Buyer2  Banana  Kg        5
Buyer2  Banana  Kg        5
                                    10
Buyer2  Coconut Count    20
                                    20
Buyer4  Papaya  Count   500
                                    500
Buyer4  Mango   Count   200
                                    200
Buyer5  Banana  Kg       15
Buyer5  Banana  Kg       15
                                     30
```

Comment: Why have you left this question open?, are you not happy with the answer below?, to me it seems fairly correct?

Answer (score 1):

This simplest thing to do is create multiple groups. SO in your example you would use three groups, one for buyer, product, and unit. You can then use a variable to sum the quantity and have it reset with the unit group.

Below is a basic example JRXML, that you can adapt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report1" language="groovy" pageWidth="612" pageHeight="792" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="b478862e-b118-4290-8664-eae9b2966b31">
    <parameter name="GROUP_BY" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[$F{field1}]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <field name="buyer" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="product" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="unit" class="java.lang.Number"/>
    <field name="quantity" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <variable name="sumQuantity" class="java.lang.Number" resetType="Group" resetGroup="unit" calculation="Sum"/>
    <group name="Buyer">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{buyer}]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
    <group name="product">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{product}]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
    <group name="unit">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{unit}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupFooter>
            <band height="26">
                <textField>
                    <reportElement uuid="d1f95335-0fee-4d75-ac0d-74f0dc478a78" x="400" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                    <textElement/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{sumQuantity}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </groupFooter>
    </group>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="21" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="c4ee8763-fb32-4805-9bcd-4b407bd7ae35" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[buyer]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="5c5e099b-f2b4-4c98-b428-bc3983711136" x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[product]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="1bff9ddd-fa17-4b7f-bc00-032653cf2307" x="200" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[unit]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="94e75612-cee4-45e9-97c0-a0d1b8ac6269" x="300" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[quantity]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="92e83a6d-198f-4ee1-95eb-295cb2415136" x="400" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[total]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="23" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="927b66fa-f4aa-4acf-ac85-fde9164bc974" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{buyer}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="f5e8d24f-5529-489d-94b9-78b86b09adda" x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{product}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="9c9f129b-64c7-40d5-a0a9-af2069d58296" x="200" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{unit}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="d9443c16-dcac-4a72-b85f-d961c215aee4" x="300" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{quantity}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```